# How to get the user location legally according to the new android policy

Tags: android

According to the new Android policy: "Apps that collect information (such as the user's location or behavior) without the user's knowledge (spyware) are prohibited.".

Now, do I need to notify the user the app will collect or use the GPS information when the app is running?

or is it enough to notify the user only once throught the permissions menu that appears when installing new app?

Comment: **"... is it enough to notify the user only once throught the permissions menu that appears when installing new app?"** : No, I wouldn't risk assuming that would be enough. Probably the majority of Android users don't understand what the various permissions mean. I would definitely provide a popup dialog explaining exactly what your app does and why / how it uses the location data. Also, as Aksh points out, there should be an enable / disable option which they can access even if they agreed to your popup details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my concern you should notify user about that at the time of installation and whenever user uses the application, and you should also provide the Enable and Disable functionality so that user will trust your application and will use for long time..